# Git : Merge strategy for two developers working on same file

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I get confused with gitlab merge.

Here is the case:

#### **[Company Repo]**

1. Let's say that company repository on `gitlab.com/bfi/sandbox`
2. company repository has branch `master` (snapshot of production) and `test` (snapshot of QA)
3. each developer must fork the company repo to their repo work

#### **[Feature Request on August 10]**

There are two feature to be done developers : X will works on feature 1, and Y will works on feature 2.
So X fork company repo, create branch `feature_1` on `gitlab.com/x/sandbox`.
Y also fork company repo, create branch `feature_2` on `gitlab.com/y/sandbox`

Both happens to work on same file : `myfile.txt`. Original content of `myfile.txt` is blank

#### **[X commit on august 11]**

Let's just say on August 11, X:

1. commit his change to `x/sandbox:feature_1` AND create MR to `x/sandbox:test`
2. create merge request from `x/sandbox:test` to `company/sandbox:test`

so `myfile.txt` content become

```
feature 1 line 1 by X
```

in these places:

- `x/sandbox:feature_1`
- `x/sandbox:test`
- `company/sandbox:test`

QA begin test feature 1

#### [Y commit on August 12]

On august 12:

1. Y commit his change to `y/sandbox:feature_2` `y\sandbox:test`. Content of myfile.txt (on y) is

```
feature 2 line 1 by Y
```

So far so good

2. Y submit merge request to from `y/sandbox:test` to `company/sandbox:test`. Here he got merge conflict, so Y contact X, and solve the conflict. Contenct of `myfile.txt` became

```
feature 1 line 1 by X
feature 2 line 1 by Y
```

Y also contact X, so X pull `company/sandbox:test` into `x/sandbox:test`
This content (2 merged lines) now occurs on

- `x/sandbox:test`
- `y/sandbox:test`
- `company/sandbox:test`

One line (only contains feature 2) occurs on `y/sandbox:feature_2`

Another QA begins testing feature 2, taken from company repo

#### [QA Found bug for feature 1 (worked by X) on August 13]

X works on the bug, so on `x/sandbox:feature_1`, the content of `myfile.txt` become

```
feature 1 line 1 by X
feature 1 line 2 (bugfix) by X
```

Notice the missing line. `feature 2 line 1 by Y` is not here, so when X submit merge request for bugfix to `x/sandbox:test`, git will throw conflict.
Conflict resolution is either:

- use OURS (`feature 1 line 1 & feature 1 line 2`)
- use THEIRS (`feature 1 line 1 & feature 2 line 1`)
- manually merge both (contains whole 3 lines)

Whichever resolution, it will change the source branch `x/sandbox:feature_1`.

#### The question

How can X achieve following thing on August 13:

- `x/sandbox:feature_1` keep only 2 lines (`feature 1 line 1 & feature 1 line 2`)
- `company/sandbox:test` keep the whole lines (feature 1 & feature 2)

The case is that 2 QA must works on feature 1 & feature 2. While feature 1 is scheduled to go live first, without waiting feature 2. In this case, if X choose :
  - OURS : QA will not be able to test feature2, since company repo not contains it
  - THEIRS: QA will not be able to test feature 1
  - merge manually to contains all lines : `x/sandbox:feature_1` will contains line from feature 2. This means if feature 1 is scheduled to live on August 14, while feature 2 is scheduled on August 20, deployment on August 14 will also contains line from feature 2.

So what is the strategy to

- X only deploy `feature 1` (& its bugfix) on August 14
- Y deploy `feature 2` (including `feature 1`) on August 20?

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with just merging in features via pull requests when you want them to come back into the parent branch?  I think you may be overcomplicating things here.

Comment: Is there some reason why `x/sandbox:feature_1` should keep only 2 lines?  Since he is eventually pushing his edits to the `test` branch, he should merge `test` onto `feature_1` before making edits.  He can also pull `test` from the company repo and merge it onto his `feature_1` before issuing merge request, to check out there is not conflict.

Comment: The problem is on time. If x merge `test` onto `feature1` that means his `feature1` now has all lines (including `feature2`). Eventually this must be done, but since `feature1` must go live first to production (on aug 14), X must not put anything related to `feature1` on that deployment